# UI Bootstrap (AngularJS) modal is not working

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this practice project that I am working on, but I cant get my UI Boostratp modal working. Using example from the site https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal I have been trying to implement this feature but without success.

I believe that this is because of that I do not have the knowledge to integrate demo code to my MVC style project (I have separate app.js, controller, and service files), and this one file example is rather confusing to me.

My folder/file structure:

[image: Here is my folder structure:]

Now, I have tried various things, including making a separate controller, and separate view for modal content (that's why I have bookDetailes.html and bookDetailesConreoller.js files but they are currently out of order - not connected in app.js's stat provider and their code is under comment). This is where I am:

A have a list of basic book details retrieved from data base and printed out in book.html view via data-ng-repeat. In every repeat I have an Action button that is supposed to open modal for editing or deleting that entry.

Here is my book.html file where I have nested the demo markup code from UI Bootsratp site:

```
<h4 class="text-center"><strong>Book Collection</strong></h4>
<br>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Publisher</th>
            <th>City of Publishing</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Action
            <th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-ng-init="init()">
        <tr data-ng-repeat="book in books">
            <td>{{book.id}}</td>
            <td>{{book.image}}</td>
            <td>{{book.title}}</td>
            <td>{{book.author}}</td>
            <td>{{book.yearOfPublishing}}</td>
            <td>{{book.publisher}}</td>
            <td>{{book.cityOfPublishing}}</td>
            <td>{{book.genre}}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-ng-click="open()">Action</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

As you can see, this last part after table tag is supposed to be modal markup taht is called when Action button is pressed and command "open()" i passed to bookController.js via data-ng-click.

My bookControler.js:

```
collectionsApp.controller('bookController', function($scope, bookService,
        $state) {

    var books = [];

    $scope.save = function() {
        bookService.save($scope.book, onSaveDelete);
    }

    $scope._delete = function(id) {
        for (book in books) {
            if (book.id === id) {
                bookService._delete(book, onSaveDelete);
            }
        }
    }

    $scope.edit = function(id) {
        for (book in books) {
            if (book.id === id) {
                $scope.book;
            }
        }
    }

    $scope.init = function() {
        bookService.list(onInit);
    }

    // <-- Beginning of the modal controller code I inserted (and adopted) from the example: 

    $scope.items = [ 'item1', 'item2', 'item3' ];

    $scope.open = function(size) {

        modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl : 'myModalContent.html',
            controller : ModalInstanceCtrl,
            size : size,
            resolve : {
                items : function() {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
            $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        }, function() {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };

    var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

        $scope.items = items;
        $scope.selected = {
            item : $scope.items[0]
        };

        $scope.ok = function() {
            $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    };

    // <-- Ending of the modal code I have inserted from the example.

    onSaveDelete = function(response) {
        if (response.data.status === 'success') {
            $scope.init();
        } else {
            alert("DEBUG ALERT: SAVE/DELETE FAIL");
        }
    };

    onInit = function(response) {
        $scope.books = response.data;
        books = response.data;
    };

});
```

Now, like this, code is working in the seance that data-ng-repeat is working and I get list of database entries on page load. But when I click on the Action button i get this error message in the console:

[image]

But when I add $modal to may code like this:

```
collectionsApp.controller('bookController', function($scope, bookService,
        $state, $modal) {

    var books = [];
...
```

I get this error on page load:

[image]

Can someone help me understand and implement modals to my project? Thanks in advance... ;)

Comment: In your question you wrote `&modal`. Is that a typo? Otherwise this will probably be the reason ;)

Comment: change &modal to $modal should work

Comment: @muenchdo Yes, that was I typo I made only in this post, in my project i have tried $modal. I will edit my post now and make a not of this edit. Thank you for the notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this,

```
angular.module('Urapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: That was I typo I made only in this post, in my project i have tried $modal. I edited my post now and made an edit note.

Comment: @PapiTheTypecatser still you are getting same error. ?

Comment: Yes, taht was only this-post-typo, in my IDE a have entered correct $modal when I was testing program, but when I was writing code in this post my mind wondered away and I have entered &modal instead of $modal. Error is still the same.

Comment: @PapiTheTypecatser : have you included ui.bootstrap.  'angular.module('Urapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);'